# Ubuntu Rescue mode, linux partition shows as unlocated

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, grubrescue

I have  laptop where I had dual-boot set with Ubuntu LTS and Windows 10. I lent it to a friend but when he game me it back i switched it on and only appeared grub rescue mode. I tried to recover it manually from rescue mode directly. I listed partitions with ls but when i try to list whats inside each partition it gives me filesystem error.

Then i tried to recover it from a live bootable USB. I listed partitions with `sudo fdisk -l` and got the following output:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1459982336 bytes, 2851528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4e1f1e3e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  25167871  25165824    12G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2  *     25167872  25372671    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        25372672 290453503 265080832 126.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       290455550 488396799 197941250  94.4G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       454297600 488396799  34099200  16.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7742685184 bytes, 15122432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x02c7c726

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15122431 15120384  7.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

It doesnt show any Linux partition at all but it should be the one on /dev/sda4. Then i typed `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt`
and got the following output `mount: /dev/sda4 is not a valid block device`

Looking on Gparted..
[Gparted_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDPp.png)

dev/sda4/ appears to be an extended partition but the space where Ubuntu should be installed shows as unllocated. It looks like if Ubuntu partition got deleted.. what could it be? could i recover files contained in there? could i fix grub2 and recover it at all? :(

Thank u for yr help